# Не могу найти ошибку в коде

Tags: массивы, delphi

В массиве должно выводиться среднее арифметическое значение элементов Y(20), удовлетворяющих условию y(i)>0

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
uses unit2;



{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  y:array[1..20] of integer;
  i,s,k,n,code: integer;
  ny:real;
  y_s,i_s,n_s,s_s,k_s,ny_s: string;
  FilMatrix:TextFile;
begin
  n_s:=edit1.Text;
  Val(n_s,n,code);

  Form1.Memo.Lines.Clear;
  randomize;

  for i:=1 to n do
    if y[i]>0 then
    begin
      y[i]:=random(31)-20;
      str(y[i]:10,y_s);
      form1.memo.Lines.Text:=Form1.memo.lines.text+y_s+' ' +chr(13);
      s:=0;
      k:=0;
      k:=k+1;
      s:= s+y[i];
      ny:=s/k;

      AssignFile(FilMatrix,'mass_y.txt');
      rewrite(FilMatrix);
      for i 1 to n do
      begin
        write(FilMatrix,y[i]:10);
        if Frac(i/5)=0 then 
          writeln(FilMatrix); {перевод курсора на следующую строку}
        closeFile(FilMatrix);
      end;
    end; 
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  y_s: string;
  FilMatrix:TextFile;
begin
  Form2.Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  AssignFile(FilMatrix,'mass_y.txt');
  reset(FilMatrix);
  while not EOF(FilMatrix) do
  begin
    readln(FilMatrix,y_s);
    form2.memo1.lines.text:=form2.memo1.lines.text+y_s+chr(13);
  end;
  closeFile(FilMatrix);

  Form2.show;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.Close;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Трудность Вашей задачи в том, что этот код почти полностью состоит из ошибок, поэтому сказать как "найти (одну) ошибку" невозможно. Разбейте большую задачу на маленькие. Например. 1. Заполнить массив из двадцати целых чисел случайными значениями. 2. ...

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, как это, разбить на маленькие, мне нужно найти среднее значение положительных чисел, для этого нужны сумма и количество положительных чисел, там ведь все взаимосвязано.. Вы не могли бы пожалуйста указать на ошибки, которые Вы увидели?

Comment: Еще у вас используется Unit2, а мы его не видим. Плюс, судя по всему, строки кода копировались из другого проекта. Соглашусь с @Igor, очень много ошибок, давайте разбирать по частям.

Answer (score 3):

Так, попробуем.

Ваш массив из 20-ти элементов (если да, то зачем нужна переменная `n`, задаваемая пользователем?), или произвольной длинны?

Не стесняйтесь оборачивать блоки кода после `if`, `for` и т.п. в `begin/end` - возьмите за правило делать это всегда, даже если блок состоит всего из одной строки кода.

Рассмотрим вот этот фрагмент:

```
for i:=1 to n do
  if y[i]>0 then
  begin
    y[i]:=random(31)-20;
```

Что здесь происходит раньше: присвоение значения `y[i]` или сравнение его с нулем? А что должно?

Далее. Вы хотите накапливать сумму положительных элементов массива. Значит инициализация этой сумы нулем `s := 0;` должна происходить до цикла, а не в нем.

Вам нужно посчитать среднее всех положительных элементов. Значит никакого деления внутри цикла быть не должно, а должен быть счетчик количества просуммированных элементов.

Ну и "арбуз на этом торте" - внутренний цикл с записью в файл, использующий ту же самую переменную (что и внешний цикл) в качестве счетчика цикла.